# Javascript functions scope - best way to structure

Tags: javascript, scope

What's the best way to structure this..  returning an object with several functions..
Fails on this.put ("this" not in scope anymore)..

```
return {
    put: function(o, cb){
        fs.writeFile(fn, JSON.stringify(o, null, 4), function(e, r){
                if(e) throw e;
                cb(o);
            })      
        },
    setItem: function(n, v, cb){
            this.get(function(o){
                o[n] = v;
                this.put(o, cb);
            })
    }
```

Comment: `this.put` is inside `this.get(function)`, so the inner `this` do not refers to returned object. Use this: `setItem:function(){var that=this;this.get(function(){that.put();});}`.

Comment: @Passerby That depends how `get` calls (or whatever it actually does with) the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change

```
setItem: function(n, v, cb){
        this.get(function(o){
            o[n] = v;
            this.put(o, cb);
        })
}
```

to

```
setItem: function(n, v, cb){
        var myobject = this;
        this.get(function(o){
            o[n] = v;
            myobject.put(o, cb);
        })
}
```

The "this" variable will be overridden within the this.get ... but the myobject variable will not be.

Answer (score 0):

yet another alternative is to .bind() the right *this* into place:

```
return {
    put: function(o, cb){
        fs.writeFile(fn, JSON.stringify(o, null, 4), function(e, r){
                if(e) throw e;
                cb(o);
            })      
        },
    setItem: function(n, v, cb){
            this.get(function(o){
                o[n] = v;
                this.put(o, cb);
            } .bind(this) );
    }
}
```